# Transfer times in Stuttgart airpot

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, stuttgart

Toward the end of summer, I'll be flying from Tbilisi to London via Stuttgart. The transfer time on the ticket is 50 minutes. Stuttgart airport's website indicates 30 minutes as the minimum transfer time.

On my first flight, I'm sitting in row 4 - nearly the front of the plane - and the baggage will be checked in through to the final destination.

If I miss the connecting flight, it won't be the end of the world (provided the airline will provide appropriate support - rebooking on the next flight, food vouchers, etc.) - however I'd rather make it. How likely am I to actually make the connecting flight to London?

The additional complexity is that I will be travelling with 3 children aged between 7 and 9 (i.e. one adult with 3 children).

Comment: Stuttgart walking times are short once you're inside the terminal, but I think they have a lot of outfield positions that will slow you down, and row 4 won't help you. But it's been a while since I last arrived at that airport, and I know too little about the current layout of arrivals for this to make a proper answer...

Answer (score 2):

> How likely am I to actually make the connecting flight to London?

I'd say 80%+. If everything works as it should, you should be fine. Things can always go wrong, but that's hard to predict:

1. You might get bussed instead of a jet bridge. That takes a few minutes longer especially if it's only one bus and you have to wait for a straggler or a person who needs extra help.
2. Your inbound flight is late.
3. You have a paperwork hiccup (Covid test, vaccination records, entry forms, Visa, passport, etc.)

Assuming this is Eurowings, missing it is not much of a problem. They will just put you on the next flight to London and on most dates there are two more the same day after the one you missed.

> The additional complexity is that I will be travelling with 3 children aged between 7 and 9 (i.e. one adult with 3 children).

If you feel you need extra time, you shouldn't book a tight connection. This being said, Stuttgart is a small airport and 7-9 are typically don't require a lot of extra time. Of course, that depends a lot on the personalities and behavioral patterns of the specific kids involved.

If you want to be extra careful: chase them all to the bathroom in the plane about 1 hour or so before landing in Stuttgart. This may save you a pit stop on the ground.

Comment: _If you want to be extra careful: chase them all to the bathroom in the plane about 1 hour or so before landing in Stuttgart. This may save you a pit stop on the ground._  This is understatement of a good idea! Generally, they are average 7-9 yo kids, but I don't expect much behavioural problems :)